# SQL Add Integer Column to Date column

Tags: sql, postgresql

This works:

```
SELECT "date", "value"::Int, "date" + interval '1' day AS "computed" 
FROM "tab1"
```

but what if I want to add a variable from the table to a timestamp?

```
SELECT "date", "value"::Int, "date" + interval "value" day AS "computed" 
FROM "tab1"
```

This fails.

Comment: `date` is a `date` value then you can simply use `"date" + "value"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interval is like a number, and can be multiplied

```
SELECT "date", "value"::Int, "date" + interval '1' day * "value" AS "computed" 
FROM "tab1"
```

Not sure if your cast to int was indicative of it being e.g. some decimal like 1.5, but if it is then 1.5 days would be added. If you want just the integral part of `value` to matter, then consider something like `"date" + interval '1' day * "value"::int`

Comment: FYI there is also a `make_interval(days => value)` function.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html

Comment: There is, though not in oracle (but this works there too) - too much to keep in my brain about the differences between db vendors; I'll take any common ground I can remember! :)